# Yandex SppechKit TTS Сохранение файла

Tags: php, wav, tts, yandex-speechkit

пытаюсь написать простенький скрипт на php который должен:

1. Загрузить из файла некоторый текст из которого нужно синтезировать голосовое сообщение
2. Сделать запрос к Yandex SpeechKit Cloud API TTS
3. Сохранить результат в отдельный wav файл

Собственно скрипт есть и он даже как-то работает:

```
<?php 
      $str = file_get_contents("inputfile.txt");//файл с текстом
      $qs = http_build_query(array("format" => "wav","lang" => "ru-RU","speaker" => "jane","key" => "APIKEY","emotion" => "good", "text" => $str)); // параметры запроса
      $ctx = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET","header"=>"Referer: \r\n"))); 
      $soundfile = file_get_contents("https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?".$qs, false, $ctx); //выполнение запроса
      $file = fopen("testfile.wav", "w"); //файл для хранения
      fwrite($file, $soundfile); //запись в файл
      fclose($file);
     ?>
```

Но в файл записывается только первые неколько десятков байт от WAV что-то вроде:

```
RIFF$   WAVEfmt      Ђ»   w   data
```

Как записать в файл все целиком? Спасибо.

Comment: Код прекрасно работает.

 При исполнении не возникает ошибок? И включен ли `error_reporting(E_ALL)` ?

Comment: Код работает и ошибок не возникает, но в файле вместо полноценных данных только вот эти несколько десятков байт. Из java все прекрасно работает, но нужен именно скрипт на php.

Comment: Выяснилось, что код не отрабатывает для русского ввода. С английским все хорошо работает.

Comment: именно русский текст запускал для проверки - проблем нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась путем конвертации входного текста в UTF8. Полностью рабочий код:

```
<?php 
 $str = file_get_contents("inputfile.txt");
 $str = utf8_encode($str);
 $qs = http_build_query(array("format" => "wav","lang" => "ru-RU","speaker" => "jane","key" => "APIKEY","emotion" => "good", "text" => $str)); // параметры запроса
 $ctx = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET","header"=>"Referer: \r\n")));
 $soundfile = file_get_contents("https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?".$qs, false, $ctx); 
 $file = fopen("testfile1.wav", "w");
 fwrite($file, $soundfile);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Всем большое спасибо.